# Read, Write, Transform Multiple XML in HDFS XSL

Tags: xml, parsing, csv, xslt, hdfs

I am trying to apply a stylesheet in hdfs, which converts String of xml into csv. I have stored the xml as an array of Strings. The program works perfectly fine with one application of the stylesheet. However, when it iterates through a loop the transformation fails. It will only transform the first element of the String array into a csv. Afterwards I get the below errors.

```
public class xmlToCsv {

public void xmlTransform (String[] xmlFiles, String out_hdfsPath, String styleSheet) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {

        //Set system hdfs config
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(configuration);


        //filesteam for stylesheet application in hdfs
        Path style_path = new Path(styleSheet);
        FSDataInputStream style_stream = hdfs.open(style_path);
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(style_stream);

        for (int i = 1; i < xmlFiles.length; i++){
            //application of xsl tranformation
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFiles[i])));

            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);

            //output path of csv file
            Path out_path = new Path(out_hdfsPath+i);
            OutputStream os = hdfs.create(out_path);

            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(os);
            transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
            os.close();
        }

}
```

}

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Stream closed'
           :Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Stream closed
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1015)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:789)
        at hdfs_rw.xmlToCsv.xmlTransform(xmlToCsv.java:55)
        at hdfs_rw.hdfs_rw.main(hdfs_rw.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:903)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:704)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:431)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:506)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:466)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:568)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:974)
        ... 9 more
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:903)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:704)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:431)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:506)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:466)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.XSLTC.compile(XSLTC.java:568)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:974)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:789)
        at hdfs_rw.xmlToCsv.xmlTransform(xmlToCsv.java:55)
        at hdfs_rw.hdfs_rw.main(hdfs_rw.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
```

out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize that.